# Understanding the behavior of sequential conditionals

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, nested

Somehow, I have made it this far in Python without having an explicit understanding of how conditionals work (especially when nested in loops). I came to this realization while I was designing an algorithm that iterates over a list, and builds a new list at a 1:1 ratio.

For example:

```
x = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
y = []

for z in x:
    if z == #whatever:
        y.append(f'{z}{'is good'}'
    if z == #whatever:
        y.append(f'{z}{'is bad'}'
```

One would expect that y and x would both be the same length by the end of the loop. That is not what happened, and I had multiple repeats in my `y` list, with different conditional results. I.E. an element may have been appended three times and triggered a number of different conditionals in the statement.

So, I began testing and just became even more confused:

```
import re

regexp = r'webaddy'
regexp2 = r'Web Addy'
zd = ['test', 'webaddy55', 'sss', 'Web Addy:99']


for xc in zd:
    if re.match(regexp, xc):
        print('This has webaddy' + ' | ' + xc)
    if re.match(regexp2, xc):
        print('This has Web Addy' + ' | ' + xc)
    else:
        print("Works" + ' | ' + xc)
```

My expected output for this would be:

```
Works | test
This has webaddy | webaddy55
Works | sss
This has Web Addy | Web Addy:99
```

The actual output is:

```
Works | test
This has webaddy | webaddy55
Works | webaddy55
Works | sss
This has Web Addy | Web Addy:99
```

How could it have 5 outputs with only 4 elements in the list? What is wrong with how I am structuring my conditionals? I was under the impression that once a conditional is met, the loop moves on to the next item in the list, what is actually going on here?

Comment: Did you mean to use `elif`? The two `if` statements in your code are not disjoint, so it's possible that both matches occur and you append twice. In the second example, if the first block matches and the second doesn't, you'll get two prints--the first `if` and the final `else`, which is only dependent on the result from the middle `if`.

Comment: Your code doesn't have any nested conditionals, you execute them sequentially.

Comment: @ggorlen I believe the explanation of 'else' solves my main problem. What should I use if I simply want to execute when something hasn't fulfilled ANY of the previous conditionals. I.E. a sort of standard procedure if nothing has been triggered.

Comment: Use `else` for that. It's just like English, "if you're thirsty, drink water else if you're hungry, eat food else do something else". If you want to account for the possibility that you might be hungry and thirsty, you have to add a third branch in your `if`-`elif`-`else to account for both hunger and thirst at the same time using `and`.

Comment: @ggorlen Hmm, but didn't you say in your first comment that the final `else` is dependent on the middle `if`?

Comment: Yes, `else` is attached to the nearest `if` and any `elif`s that might happen to come between them. If you have `if foo` followed by `if bar else baz` then the first `if foo` is completely independent of the `bar`/`baz` block and should be separated with whitespace to make it clear. I recommend reading a tutorial on `if`/`elif`/`else` if it's still confusing.